Причастные предикативы — это слова категории состояния (СКС) или нет?
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
В комнате натоптано. Хорошо сказано. Будет сделано. Так принято. Запрещено разговаривать. Было решено ехать.
Краткие страдательные причастия в безличных предложениях сходны со словами категории состояния (СКС), но можно ли их отнести к таким словам?  Да и что такое СКС — часть речи или нет?
Это дискуссия по материалам на учебном портале.
Слова категории состояния образуют следующие 
группы:
2. слова, соотносимые по грамматической форме с 
краткими страдательными причастиями среднего рода:
обнаружено
указано
накурено
решено
выяснено
заперто

Вопрос продолжает начатую ранее тему.
Также из ответов Справочной службы
 Вопрос:  Правомерно ли выделять слова категории 
 состояния в самостоятельную часть речи? 
 Ответ: Лингвисты высказывают разные точки 
 зрения на этот вопрос. В академической «Русской 
 грамматике» такая часть речи не выделяется. 

Поэтому пока СКС — это так называемые слова категории состояния.

Ответ автора сайта.
В грамматике русского языка нет однозначного подхода к определению слов категории состояния. К примеру, лингвист В.В.Виноградов относил к этой части речи такие краткие страдательные причастия, как
продано
заявлено
привезено
принято и пр.
Источник: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/kategoriia-sostoianiia.html

Серж, авторитеты есть разные, но есть определенный подход к решению проблемы. Вот ваши лингвисты перечисляют грамматические признаки, но мне общая морфология в их изложение кажется неубедительной. Неизменяемость? Даже она под вопросом. Тем не менее они не дают ссылок на АГ-80 или Виноградова, а пишут однозначно. И вероятно, не видят разницу между качественным признаком СКС и действием для предикативных причастий. А Кустова разделяет эти группы. Ссылаться приходится, когда даже школьники замечают несоответствие. И в словарь Кузнецова тоже пусть заглядывают, если им авторитет дорог.

Я понимаю ваше недовольство. И с вами согласен. Насчёт Виноградова надо поискать информацию.

Серж, спасибо за участие в теме. Посмотрела Литневскую, у нее есть материал о том,что не все учебные комплексы рассматривают СКС, как и не все лингвисты. Про причастные предикативы нет ничего, но есть мнение о том, что слова категории состояния иногда считаются подгруппой наречий (предикативные наречия). Интересно бы узнать мнение Грамоты относительно причастных предикативов. Кстати, в Сети при разборе слова "видно" для СКС пишут предикатив, а для " запрещено" краткое причастие  (форма полного причастия).

СКС относительно новая часть речи. Действительно, не все лингвисты ее рассматривают. Подробнее об этой теме надо статьи, в школьных учебниках не стоит искать подробностей.

Этот сайт предназначен именно для школьников и др. пользователей, изучающих язык. И я бы на их месте убрала бы из темы причастные предикативы. Даже если Виноградов когда-то писал об этом, в современном понимании темы предикативам в СКС делать нечего. Ни в словарях, ни в разборах их  к СКС не относят.

Вы абсолютно правы!

ПРИЧАСТНЫЕ ПРЕДИКАТИВЫ В ТРУДАХ В. В. ВИНОГРАДОВА И СОВРЕМЕННЫХ ШКОЛЬНЫХ И ВУЗОВСКИХ УЧЕБНИКАХ
Часть 1. В. В. Виноградов о причастиях вообще и причастных предикативах в составе СКС  в частности

Виктор Владимирович Виноградов. Русский язык (Грамматическое
учение о слове) Учебное пособие. — 4-е изд. — М.: Русский язык, 2001. — 720 с.
Книга выдающегося учёного академика Виноградова В. В. 
представляет собой классический труд по русской 
филологии. 
В ней решены важнейшие проблемы грамматической теории. 
Дано описание морфологии русского языка. Изложены идеи, 
позволяющие составить представление об основных 
положениях синтаксического учения автора Первый выпуск 
исследования Современный русский язык (М., 1938) отражает 
взгляды русских лингвистов конца XIX и первой половины XX 
столетия.


Итак, 1-е издание вышло в 1938 году, в Сети доступно онлайн 3-е издание 1986 года. Скоро будет отмечаться 100-летний юбилей книги, поэтому возникает вопрос: насколько актуальны взгляды Виноградова в теме СКС для современной общеобразовательной школы. Нужно ли школьникам при морфологическом разборе СКС учитывать учение Виноградова? Ведь в то время понимание темы только складывалось, между известными учеными велось обсуждение, поэтому труд Виноградова в какой-то мере отражает этот дискуссионный характер.

Но вот в учебных материалах явно школьной направленности дается такое объяснение:
В грамматике русского языка нет однозначного подхода к 
определению слов категории состояния. К примеру, лингвист 
В.В.Виноградов относил к этой части речи такие краткие 
страдательные причастия, как продано явлено, привезено, 
принято и пр. 


Поэтому там предлагается: давайте будем и мы относить причастные предикативы  к СКС. Но насколько это правомерно? Уж очень мало эти примеры напоминают слова категории состояния. Вообще говоря, читать и комментировать учение Виноградова о причастных предикативах должны профессиональные лингвисты, так как определенные трудности там есть.


В частности, это касается ТЕРМИНОЛОГИИ. (1) Сейчас термин предикатив имеет два значения: (1) сказуемое в безличном предложении и (2) предикативное наречие, СКС, безлично-предикативное слово. Некоторые лингвисты до сих пор не выделяют СКС как часть речи и считают, что это функция наречия.

Но есть еще важный момент у Виноградова — это сравнение значений прилагательных и причастий, в том числе их  КРАТКИХ форм в функции сказуемого.

Определение причастия по статье История классификации причастия
   В.В. Виноградов: "Причастия - категория гибридных 
   глагольно-прилагательных форм". В прошлом краткие формы 
   имен прилагательных, сочетавшись с категорией времени, 
   оказались в переходной грамматической зоне, смежной с 
   глаголом. Между тем от глагола шел поток форм, 
   внедрявшихся в класс имен прилагательных. Это причастия, 
   в которых глагольность выражается как окачествленное 
   действие, приписанное предмету и определяющее его 
   наподобие имени прилагательного. Естественно, что в 
   причасти сохраняются основные семантические признаки 
   глагольности, т. е. вид и залог.


Это оглавление темы В. В. Виноградов. Русский язык (Грамматическое учение о слове): VI. Категория состояния
§ 1. Вопрос о категории состояния в русских 
грамматических трудах 
§ 2. Грамматические особенности категории состояния.
§ 3. Сближение кратких прилагательных с категорией 
состояния
§ 4. Распространение безличных форм в категории состояния
§ 5. Грамматические особенности безличных слов в 
категории состояния 
§ 6. Вопрос об отношении безлично-предикативных слов к 
краткой форме прилагательных среднего рода прилагательных 
§ 7. Категория состояния и качественные наречия.
§ 8. Тесная связь между категорией состояния и разрядами 
качественно-обстоятельственных наречий, выражающих 
характер, образ действия и состояния
§ 9. Процесс обеспредмечивания имен существительных и 
пути движения их в категорию состояния.
§ 10.    Грамматическое оформление фразеологических 
сочетаний и единств при посредстве категории состояния
§ 11.    Роль категории состояния в грамматической 
системе современного русского языка



Как видно, Виноградов не рассматривает ни в одном из параграфов причастные предикативы, а основное внимание уделяет наречиям, кратким прилагательными на О и существительным, то есть словам с признаковым значением в функции сказуемого. Причастные предикативы, для которых эта эта функция естественна, только упоминаются при сравнении.

Вывод

Как решает Виноградов вопрос об отнесенности  причастных предикативов к СКС, пусть решают лингвисты (например, из Грамоты), но по большому счету для школы важнее вопрос о том, как был решен этот вопрос в современном языкознании. И вот тогда становится ясно, что как в школьных, так и в вузовских учебниках (после 2000-го года) причастные предикативы не относят к СКС, но при этом они используются в безличных предложения наряду с безличными глаголами и СКС.
В словарях в качестве СКС (в функции сказуемого) числятся всего несколько модальных причастных предикативов, например: не разрешено, не велено др., которые синонимичны словам можно, нельзя и др.
ЧАСТЬ 2. ПРИЧАСТНЫЕ ПРЕДИКАТИВЫ В СОВРЕМЕННЫХ ШКОЛЬНЫХ И ВУЗОВСКИХ УЧЕБНИКАХ (КРАТКИЙ ОБЗОР)

Кустова Г. И. Синтаксис современного русского языка. Курс лекций, 2013 год. Учебник для педвузов

Основными способами выражения главного члена безличного
предложения являются: (1) безличные глаголы;  (2) слово нет и его аналоги;  (3) слова категории состояния;  (4) краткое страдательное причастие ср. рода на О.
Причастные предикативы делятся на группы: (1) модальные: запрещено, не велено; (2) значение наличия или отсутствия: наготовлено, запасено; (3) значение речи, информации: сказано, замечено, решено.

В. И. Казарина  Простое предложение в аспекте структурно-семантического подхода. Монография, 2-е издание,  стереотипное; учебник для филологических факультетов.

По структуре и семантике  безличные предложения традиционно дифференцируются на две группы: предложения глагольные и предложения именные.
Глагольный тип безличных предложений представлен безличными глаголами: смеркается, нездоровится, не спится, пришлось.
К именным безличным относятся предложения, предикатив которых представлен словами категории состояния, известной в лингвистике также как предикативные наречия или предикативы.
ОСОБЫЙ ТИП безличного предложения образуют предложения, сказуемое которых выражено кратким страдательными причастием на О с суффиксами -ен и -т. Предложения этой разновидности используются, когда нужно представить состояние  как результат законченного действия.

Учебник для вузов Г.Ф. Рахимкуловой «Морфология современного русского языка»

Рассказано о двух подходах лингвистов к СКС: (1) СКС — это самостоятельная часть речи (Щерба, Виноградов и др.). (2) СКС входит к класс наречий на особых правах (Шапиро и др.). Дается перечень лексико-грамматических разрядов  СКС (физ. состояние, модальная оценка, состояние природы и ее восприятие органами чувств. Особо отмечается, что это неизменяемая форма, кроме степени сравнения, а также наличие временных форм и форм наклонения (было тепло, будет холодно, было бы смешно).

Гольцова Н. Г. Русский язык 10 — 11 классы. 4-е изд, 2007 г.

Перечень СКС аналогичный, дается схема разбора: Мне грустно оттого, что я тебя люблю.
 1. Грустно — слово категории состояния, так как обозначает 
 психическое состояние человека.
 2. Не изменяется.
 3. Является сказуемым в безличном предложении.

Вариант разбора у Литневской: Было уже поздно.
 поздно — категория состояния, начальная форма поздно;
 пост. признаки: выражает оценку, неизменяемое;
 непост. признаки: нет;
 синт. роль: часть сказуемого.


РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Материал дан по учебнику для педвузов Кустовой Г. И. Синтаксис современного русского языка. Курс лекций.
1. О терминологии
Предикат —  это 1) понятие, определяющее предмет суждения (субъект) и раскрывающее его содержание (в логике); 2) то же, что сказуемое (в лингвистике).
Предикатив — это предикат в безличном предложении, также предикативами (или безлично-предикативными словами)  называют СКС.
2. Что может быть сказуемым в безличных предложениях
В общем случае сказуемым в безличном предложении могут быть: (1) безличные глаголы; (2) слово нет,  глаголы с отрицанием (не было, не осталось),  также глаголы количественной семантики (мого, мало, достаточно, хватает; (3) слова категории состояния (слова на О, а также пора, жаль, недосуг и др.); (4) краткие страдательные причастия среднего рода.
3. СКС  как часть речи
СКС как часть речи должны иметь: (1) обобщенную семантику (состояние природы  и человека, модальные оценки и др.); (2) общие грамматические признаки; (3) общую синтаксическую функцию. Признаки 1 и 3 есть, но нет признака 2, который выделял бы СКС как единую группу.
Морфологически предикативы могут быть сходны с прилагательными (а также причастиями), наречиями или существительными.  См. Предикативы.
Все же основным признаком СКС является одинаковая синтаксическая функция. Возможно, поэтому СКС признают не все лингвисты.
Семантика СКС: состояние природы и человека (холодно, светло, больно, обидно, весело, интересно), восприятие (видно, слышно), модальные и оценочные значения (можно, нужно, стыдно, хорошо,тяжело), количественные значения (достаточно).
4. Почему же предикативные причастия на О не относят к СКС?
В АГ-80 такие слова названы причастными предикативами. По семантике различают: слова с модальным значением (запрещено, не суждено);  с семантикой наличия/отсутствия (наготовлено); со значением речи и информации (сказано, замечено, решено).
Несмотря на совпадение тем этих групп слов, можно заметить и принципиальное различие: СКС имеют значение качественного (нединамического) признака, а предикативные причастия имеют значение признака по действию (процессуального признака).

Пример: В комнате натоптано и накурено.

Это безличное предложение с однородными сказуемыми, выраженными кратким причастием (причастным предикативом) натоптано и СКС накурено. Но почему, ведь в обоих случаях у нас значение действия? Дело в том, что накурить в его основном значении (наполнить табачным дымом) глагол непереходный, поэтому от него нельзя образовать страдательное причастие. Соответственно, накуренный — это прилагательное (значение признака), но в краткой форме там пишется одно Н.
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
НАКУРИТЬ, -курю, -куришь; накуренный; -рен, -а, -о; св. 1. **(чем)**. 
Куря, наполнить помещение табачным дымом. Н. табаком, махоркой. // чем. 
Сжигая какое-л. ароматическое вещество, наполнить помещение ароматным 
дымом, запахом. Н. ладаном. Н. благовониями. 2. что и чего. Добыть, 
приготовить в каком-л. количестве путём перегонки (курения). Н. вина 
(устар.; о водке). Н. бочку смолы. Накуривать, -аю, -аешь; нсв.

НАКУРЕННЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Наполненный, пропитанный табачным дымом. Какой в 
комнате н. воздух. Мы вошли в н-ое помещение.

Русский орфографический словарь: накуренный; кр. ф. -ен, -ена
